# Making Powershell answer prompts with a password for SSH-key

Tags: git, powershell, ssh, automation

I've been trying to figure out how to answer a prompt in PowerShell. My use case is rather basic; after I start a PowerShell session I want my SSH keys to be loaded.

The problem I'm facing right now is that I manually have to add the passphrase for my SSH key. I'd much rather have that automated.

This is how I'm trying to do it now:

```
Add-SshKey 

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(“MyPassword01{ENTER}”)
```

And I get this error after having to manually press enter during the prompt:

```
MyPassword01 : The term 'MyPassword01' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ MyPassword01
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MyPassword01:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Another strange behaviour is that the string `MyPassword01` seems to have been written to the PowerShell window above the error, **but AFTER** the prompt:

```
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/Todai/.ssh/ps_id_rsa:
Finished!
Loading personal and system profiles took 25940ms.
~ $ MyPassword01
```

Comment: Isn't the whole point to force you to manually enter the password every time, so the password isn't stored insecurely in clear-text in a script?

Comment: If you're going to store the passphrase in a plain text file along with the key, you might as well just remove the passphrase from the key.

Comment: Absolutely right, however the script isnt pushed to the repo. It's simply used in a windows task to automatically push to my repo. But neither of your comments are helping my solve the problem. I'll take your apprehension into consideration, though

Comment: @geostocker Kenster already mentioned it: remove the passphrase from the key. Problem solved.